# Blazor - method returning all values of database table instead of filtered list from WHERE clause

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm creating a CRUD UI in Blazor Server-Side in Visual Studio 2019.

I'm trying to return a list of Accounting Codes from a SQL table as follows:

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

        namespace CrudUI.Data
        {
            public class CrudService
            {
                private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
                public CrudService(ApplicationDbContext context)
                {
                    _context = context;
                }

            public async Task<List<Codes>>

                GetCodesResponseOneAsync()

                {
                var connectionValue = _iconfiguration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("DefaultConnection").Value;
                SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionValue);
                var sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Codes WHERE ResponseLimit = 1";
                var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection1);
                connection1.Open();
                command.ExecuteReader();
                return await _context.Codes.ToListAsync();
                }
             }
         }
```

The `GetCodesResponseOneAsync` method returns every row from the `dbo.Codes` instead of just the ones with `ResponseLimit` that = 1.  How would I only return the rows from the `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Why don't you use Entity Framework Core ?

Comment: My code is the only way I ever learned to include SQL `SELECT` statements in code.  I suppose something like @FrankNielsen answer below is what you are referring to?

Comment: What you've been doing is using the old ADO.NET technology with  Entity Framework Core. I won't go into details about what you actually did. But let me suggest you to start learning Entity Framework Core which should be your tools to accessing database and retrieving data. Haven't you seen Blazor tutorials. All of them, without exception employ Entity Framework Core to access and retrieve data. Go to the docs, search for Entity Framework Core

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove:

```
               var connectionValue = _iconfiguration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("DefaultConnection").Value;
                SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionValue);
                var sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Codes WHERE ResponseLimit = 1";
                var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection1);
                connection1.Open();
                command.ExecuteReader();
```

Since it is not relevant for you(?).

And change:

`return await _context.Codes.ToListAsync();`

to

`return await _context.Codes.Where(c=>c.ResponseLimit == 1).ToListAsync();`